# TwitterOAuth: Invalid oauth_verifier parameter

Tags: php, twitter-oauth

I am at the stage of the OAuth flow where I get the OAuth verifier and have to use it to get the permanent token, however I encounter the error "Invalid oauth_verifier parameter".

```
// I get a valid oauth verifier
$oauth_verifier = filter_input(INPUT_GET, "oauth_verifier");

// I am able to run var_dump($connection) and the response seems valid
$connection = new TwitterOAuth(
    $config["consumer_key"],
    $config["consumer_secret"],
    $_SESSION["oauth_token"],
    $_SESSION["oauth_token_secret"]
);

// I believe this is where the problem lies, if I try var_dump($token) nothing shows but my original error message
$token = $connection->oauth(
    "oauth/access_token", [
        "oauth_verifier" => $oauth_verifier
     ]
);

$twitter = new TwitterOAuth(
    $config["consumer_key"],
    $config["consumer_secret"],
    $token["oauth_token"],
    $token["oauth_token_secret"]
);
```

The full error message is:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Abraham\TwitterOAuth\TwitterOAuthException: Invalid request token. in C:\xampp\htdocs\twitteroauth-master\src\TwitterOAuth.php:158 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\twitter_callback.php(34): Abraham\TwitterOAuth\TwitterOAuth->oauth('oauth/access_to...', Array) #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\twitteroauth-master\src\TwitterOAuth.php on line 158
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are running this on a local server then check your url_callback, **its not be in form of google tiny url**, it must be in the form of "http://localhost:80/file_name" OR "http://localhots:8080/file_name". If you still have this problem then write your **throw** statement in **try catch block**.
e.g.

```
try {
    throw new TwitterOAuthException($result);
}
catch(Exception $e) {

}
```

If you are running on server in spite of always check your ***url_callback should not be in the form of google tiny url*** because new twitter oauth didn't verify your google tiny url.